# Practice program crashing when trying to learn pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, crash

I'm still in the process of grasping pointers and in doing so wrote a quick meaningless program in order to practice finding pointer errors. I'm confused as to why this sample code is crashing:

```
#include <iostream>

class VehiclePart
{
public:
    VehiclePart(int);

    int GetVehiclePartNumber();
private:
    int partNumber;
};

VehiclePart::VehiclePart(int VehiclePartNumber)
{
    partNumber = VehiclePartNumber;
}

int VehiclePart::GetVehiclePartNumber()
{
    return partNumber;
}

class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle(VehiclePart* VehiclePart, int VehiclePartNumber);

    int GetVehiclePartNumber();

private:
    VehiclePart* vehiclePart;

};

Vehicle::Vehicle(VehiclePart* vehiclePart, int VehiclePartNumber)
{
    vehiclePart = new VehiclePart(VehiclePartNumber);
}

int Vehicle::GetVehiclePartNumber()
{
    return vehiclePart->GetVehiclePartNumber();
}

int main()
{
    VehiclePart* hood = nullptr;
    Vehicle car(hood, 6);

    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;

    std::cout << car.GetVehiclePartNumber();

    return 0;
}
```

I know there are better ways to go about things, like I said this is just practice for me to get used to pointers and why crashes occur. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why does your constructor take in a `VehiclePart*` if you're going to be calling new from the constructor?

Comment: You need to follow good naming convention to make your code readable: like not capitalizing variable names(first letter), or using underscore for member variables, like vehiclePart_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Vehicle::Vehicle(VehiclePart* vehiclePart, int VehiclePartNumber)
{
```

Notice that your constructor has a parameter named `vehiclePart`. Therefore,

```
    vehiclePart = new VehiclePart(VehiclePartNumber);
```

This ends up setting the constructor's parameter to the `new`ed class instance, instead of the class member of the same name.

This has nothing to do with pointers, but with scoping.